# How to create underlined UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uitextfield

*iOS noob here*

When I add a default `UITextField` to the ViewController, it looks like this:

[image]

My designer would like me to make the `UITextField` look like this (i.e. background is transparent, and just has an underline:

[image]

How do I do this? Should be asking my designer for an image to set as background for the `UITextField`. What should the image look like? Should the image be = the blue background + the underline (minus the number i guess)

Is that right?

**UPDATE**:
Based on direction below (from @Ashish Kakkad), added this code in Swift to ViewDidLoad:

```
    var bottomLine = CALayer()
    bottomLine.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, view.frame.height - 1, view.frame.width, 1.0)
    bottomLine.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    tf_editPassword.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None
    tf_editPassword.layer.addSublayer(bottomLine)
```

This almost works, but the problem is that all side borders disappear, I want just the bottom line to stay.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

@Ashish Kakkad has posted the right code but the reason it might not be working for @user1406716 is because when there is no text in the textfield, the height and width of the frame are 0 so maybe you can try the following :

Obj-C :

```
CALayer *bottomLine = [CALayer layer];
bottomLine.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 75 - 1, 300, 1.0f);
bottomLine.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
[myTextField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
[myTextField.layer addSublayer:bottomLine];
```

Swift :

```
var bottomLine = CALayer()
bottomLine.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 75 - 1, 300, 1.0)
bottomLine.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
myTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None
myTextField.layer.addSublayer(bottomLine)
```

This will ensure that the line is visible even when there is no text in the textfield.

Answer (score 19):

Try this code :

Obj-C

```
CALayer *bottomLine = [CALayer layer];
bottomLine.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, self.frame.size.height - 1, self.frame.size.width, 1.0f);
bottomLine.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
[myTextField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
[myTextField.layer addSublayer:bottomLine];
```

Swift

```
var bottomLine = CALayer()
bottomLine.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, view.frame.height - 1, view.frame.width, 1.0)
bottomLine.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
myTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None
myTextField.layer.addSublayer(bottomLine)
```

Hope it helps

**If you are using the auto-layout then try to do this code inside the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method.**

Comment: Hey I tried your (Converted it to Swift though - see updated question). It almost works. There is no bottom line though, even that disappears. The `UITextBorderStyle.None` removes all borders, would like to keep the bottom line

Comment: @user1406716 Oh! I doesn't know you are working on swift. I will check and let you know.

Comment: How do I do this if I use AutoLayout and my View is separated from my Controller? Is there a way to do it in the View?

Answer (score 7):

Use this Extension for UITextField

```
extension UITextField {

    func setUnderLine() {
        let border = CALayer()
        let width = CGFloat(0.5)
        border.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - width, width:  self.frame.size.width - 10, height: self.frame.size.height)
        border.borderWidth = width
        self.layer.addSublayer(border)
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }

}
```

Call the above function in `ViewDidLoad()` and display the textfield with an underline.

```
myTextField.setUnderLine()
```

Comment: Hi, interesting and clean solution, but seem that on my case don't work... I added the extension and inside the viewDidLoad i add the code but I can't see any changes... anyway I don't have any error so... I don't know where is the problem:

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        txtUserName.setUnderLine();
        txtPassword.setUnderLine();

Answer (score 6):

To update this with Swift 3:

```
let bottomLine = CALayer()
bottomLine.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y:first.frame.height - 1), size: CGSize(width: first.frame.width, height:  1))
bottomLine.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
first.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.none
first.layer.addSublayer(bottomLine)
```

Comment: WHAT IS first.frame.height?

Comment: @swift2geek it's a UITextField

Comment: By doing this hint just vanished.. What should I do to fix that?

Answer (score 2):

Delete borders and add underline - Swift 5:

```
extension UITextField {
    
    func addUnderLine () {
        let bottomLine = CALayer()
        
        bottomLine.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: self.bounds.height + 3, width: self.bounds.width, height: 1.5)
        bottomLine.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        
        self.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.none
        self.layer.addSublayer(bottomLine)
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For Xcode 14.2

```swift
let textField = UITextField()

textField.defaultTextAttributes = [
    NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.thick.rawValue,
    NSAttributedString.Key.underlineColor: UIColor.red
]
```