# NativeScript <TextField> with only a bottom border on iOS

Tags: ios, textfield, nativescript

I’m trying to create a NativeScript `<TextField>` that only has a single border underneath the control. There are several Stack Overflow questions that address this problem for `UITextField`s generically (such as [How to only show bottom border of UITextField in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31107994/how-to-only-show-bottom-border-of-uitextfield-in-swift)), however—for whatever reason—those same techniques don’t appear to work for NativeScript `<TextField>`s.

For instance I would expect this code to work:

```
<!-- my-page.xml -->
<TextField id="email" />

/* my-page.js */
var myTextField = page.getViewById("email").ios;
var bottomLine = new CALayer();
bottomLine.frame = CGRectMake(1, 50, 50, 1);
bottomLine.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor;
myTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;
myTextField.layer.addSublayer(bottomLine);
```

...but no border is drawn.

I’m not sure if I’m doing something wrong, or if something like {N}’s CSS implementation is overwriting my changes. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Add the following code:

```
let width = CGFloat(1.0);
bottomLine.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: myTextField.frame.size.height - width, width:  myTextField.frame.size.width, height: myTextField.frame.size.height);
bottomLine.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor;
myTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;
myTextField.layer.addSublayer(bottomLine);
```