# How to apply shadow effect on specific side of the parent view only in ios

Tags: swift, shadow, dropshadow, ios9.2

For applying shadow effect on view I am using the below code.

```
func addShadowImage(parentview:UIView){

    parentview.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
    parentview.layer.masksToBounds = false

    //for bottom shadow on view
    parentview.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,1.0)
    parentview.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
    parentview.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0


    //for bottom and right sides shadow on view
    parentview.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0,1.0)
    parentview.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    parentview.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0


    //for empty shadow on view
    parentview.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,0)
    parentview.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    parentview.layer.shadowRadius = 0

    //for bottom and right and left sides shadow on view
    parentview.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,2.0)
    parentview.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    parentview.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0

    //for four sides shadow on view
    parentview.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,0)
    parentview.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    parentview.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
}
```

Now simply call the above function with parameter type is UIView
self.addShadowImage(yourViewObject)

Then it's working fine, But this shadow effected on all its subviews.

So now I want to apply a shadow effect on specific view and specific side(i.e either left or right/bottom/top).

Comment: Help full :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31107994/how-to-only-show-bottom-border-of-uitextfield-in-swift/34653649#34653649

Comment: @mitul thanks for fast reply. Its working fine but I need to apply this effect  on view and this view is  subview of CustomTableViewCell.Its not visualise even I increase the height property

Comment: if you make sure clipToSubViews in cell.contentView is false this will work I guess.

Comment: @prajeet sorry for lately reply to you. My problem is bottom shadow is not visible between cells. All subviews are visible no issues with subviews the issue in only shadow effect.

Comment: your shadow is not visible cuz it's either clipped or overlapped by other views.

Comment: @PrajeetShrestha ok I will check it out and thank you