# Changing custom made attribute inspector value with swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield

I have made a custom attribute inspector for my text field:

```
@IBInspectable var bottomColor: UIColor = UIColor.clear {
    didSet {
        if bottomColor == UIColor.clear {
            self.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        } else {
            self.borderStyle = .bezel
        }
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

Now I want to set `bottomColor` to `red` when the form is submitted with an empty text field. Which would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm putting my logic here

For do that you need to add bottom border of UITextField

[UITextField border for bottom side only in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26800963/uitextfield-border-for-bottom-side-only-in-swift) OR [How to only show bottom border of UITextField in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31107994/how-to-only-show-bottom-border-of-uitextfield-in-swift)

Then you need to set color of this bottom border that you want

After remove same you need to set `0` width of bottom border of `UITextField` clear color of border.

Comment: thanks. that worked